# How to set button layout_constraintWidth_percent in styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-button, android-styles

I need that all the buttons of my application haves the same width and height. So I tried doing this in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="layout_constraintHeight_percent">0.15</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintWidth_percent">0.23</item>
</style>
```

It's not working, the buttons are ignoring these values. How to achieve it?

And also, once I achieve it, how can I overwrite those values for some specific buttons which I need to be bigger?

Comment: can you post button XMl code also

Comment: you shouldn't define width/heights in styles.xml

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the following to the XML for each effected button:

```
style="@style/MyButton"
```

Why is that? The button uses the attribute `android:buttonStyle` to style itself. The values you want to change deal with the layout and are not of direct interest to the button but to the *ConstraintLayout*.

During layout, *ConstraintLayout* doesn't look at the `android:buttonStyle` attribute set in the theme, so it misses the values that you set in the button style. `style="@style/MyButton"` forces the values from the button style into the attributes considered by the layout and the button will appear with your changes.

Explicitly setting the style is not as clean, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set button height and width to 0dp then it will work.

And when you need those button bigger in any case you can use percentage attribute in with in that button In that way It will ignore the style percentage constraint.